# I need to make my navbar change for smaller screen sizes

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hi I am studying and trying to make my website mobile responsive and no matter what I try have had no luck. So I have tried a range of ways to turn a menu into a mobile menu when I resize. I have also been trying to get the content to centre properly when in smaller screen. I have googled alot and worked out most now I just need help finishing it off properly.

Edit: Updated code as per request @https://stackoverflow.com/users/13447870/tobias-kristensen

```js
/* Toggle between showing and hiding the navigation menu links when the user clicks on the hamburger menu / bar icon */
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
/* Main Body */
body {
 background-image: url(Image/footballField.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 min-height: 100hv;
 min-width: 100hv;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 font-family: "Lucinda Sans", "Arial", sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black
}
/*Header with logo*/
#header {
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 padding: 10px;
} 

#container1 {
 position: relative;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 position: absolute;
 min-height: 100vh;
 width: 70%;
 margin-left: 15%;
 margin-right: 15%;
 padding-bottom:120px;
}
/* footer for all pages */
#footer { 
 position: absolute;
 clear: both;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 font-weight: 300;
 bottom: 0;
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #C61618 5%, black 100%);
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;   /* Footer height */ 
} 

.fa-facebook {
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 30px;
 width: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 background: #3B5998;
 color: white;
 margin-right: 50px;
 border-radius: 30%;
} /* Facebook Icon and link in Footer */
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*Search Field */
input:focus,
textarea:focus,
select:focus {
 outline-color: #C61618;
}/* Search Area on Header */
form.search input[type=text] {
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 17px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 float: right;
 width: 20%;
 background: white;
 margin-right: 5%;
} /* Style the search field from W3Schools*/
form.search button {
 float: right;
 width: 5%;
 padding: 10px;
 background: #C61618;
 color: white;
 font-size: 17px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-right: none;
 /* Prevent double borders */
 cursor: pointer;
} /* Style the submit button from W3Schools */
form.search button:hover {
 background: #C61618;
} /* Search button hover */
form.search::after {
 content: "";
 clear: both;
 display: table;
} /* Clear floats on Search from W3Schools */


/*Nav Bar*/
#navbar {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 40px;
 margin-right: 5%;
 margin-left: 8%;
}/*Main White Background*/
li a {
 display: inline;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 font-size: 16px;
} /*link look on Nav Bar */
#navbar ul li {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline;
 padding: 15px;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 30px; /*curved corners on buttons*/
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #C61618 5%, black 100%);
} /*Menu look*/
#navbar ul li:hover {
 background: black;
} /*Menu hover Colour*/
#navbar .btn.active {
 background: black;
} /*Menu active Colour*/


/* Text Styling */
p,
h2,
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
} /*all paragraph text*/
h1 {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 5%;
}/*position of h1*/
h2 {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 5%;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
} /*position of h2*/
h4 a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}
p {
 margin-left: 50px;
 margin-right: 50px;
 text-align: justify-all;
 line-height: 150%;
} /*format text <p> */

/*Index Page*/
#image_index {
 padding-top: 41px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 max-width: 30%
} /* Image on home page format */
#image_contact {
 padding-top: 41px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
} /* Image on home page format */
#index_table {
 float: right;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 margin-right: 5%;
} /* Table Index Page format */



/*Competitions Page */
table.c {
 table-layout: auto;
 width: 80%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.competition_table p {
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}/* format for <p> Competitions Page */
th {
 text-emphasis: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
 height: 10px;
 background-color: lightgrey;
 border-color: black;
} /* Table Header*/
table,
th,
td {
 padding: 10px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: black;
 border-width: thin;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

/* Contact Us Page */
#secretary {
 padding-top: 41px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.column1 {
 float: left;
 width: 40%;
 padding: 10px;
}
.right {
 width: 75%;
}
.row:after {
 /* Clear floats after the columns */
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}
#contact_form {
 float: right;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 margin-right: 5%;
 width: 50%;
}

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
} /*format for Contact Us form*/
input[type=text],
[type=email],
[type=tel],
select,
textarea,
email {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 12px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 4px;
 resize: vertical;
} /*format for Contact Us form*/
label {
 padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
 display: inline-block;
} /*format for Contact Us form*/
input[type=submit] {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 padding: 12px 20px;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 4px;
 cursor: pointer;
 float: right;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
} /*format for Contact Us form*/
input[type=submit]:hover {
 background-color: #C61618;
} /*format for Contact Us form*/
.col-25 {
 float: left;
 width: 25%;
 margin-top: 6px;
}
.col-75 {
 float: left;
 width: 75%;
 margin-top: 6px;
}

/*Merch Page*/
.merch_order_form {
 clear:both;
 text-align: left;
 margin-bottom: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 padding:10px;
}
.col-50 {
 float: left;
 width: 40%;
 margin-left: 10%;
 align-content: inline;
 text-align: center;
} /*Column setout for Merch & Information Pages*/
.col-45 {
 float: right;
 width: 40%;
 margin-right: 10%;
 align-content: inline;
 text-align: center;
} /*Column setout for Merch & Information Pages*/
.row:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
} /* Clear floats after the columns */
input[type=submit_merch] {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 12px 20px;
 font-size: 30px;
 border-radius: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-left: 30%;
 margin-top: 10px;
} /* Merch Page Submit Button */
input[type=submit_merch]:hover {
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #C61618 5%, black 100%);
} /* Merch Page hover change */
#subject {
 font-size: 16px;
}

/* Registration Page Submit Button */
.myButton {
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #0154FA;
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0154FA 5%, #283966 100%);
 background-color: #0154FA;
 border-radius: 30px;
 border: 1px solid #4e6096;
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 28px;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 21px 76px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #283966;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 35%;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: 70px;
} /* Merch Page Registration Button */
.myButton:hover {
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #C61618 5%, black 100%);
 background-color: #C61618;
 border: 1px solid #C61618;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #C61618;
} /* Merch Page Registration Button */
.myButton:active {
 position: relative;
 top: 1px;
} /* Merch Page Registration Button */


@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
 background-image: disabled;
     .navbar li, .navbar li a:last-child {
        display: none !important;
        visibility: hidden !important;
    }
 }
}
/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 600px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
background-image: disabled;
    .mobile_navbar li, .mobile_navbar li:last-child {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
 font-family: "Lucinda Sans", "Arial", sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
 text-align: right;
    }
 .col-25,
 .col-75,
 .col-50,
 .col-45,
 input[type=submit] input [type=submit_merch] {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 }
 #body {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0px;
  }
}
  
  #container1 {
    margin="0px";
    background-color: ="white";
  }
#mobile_navbar {
  display:flex;
margin-left: 100px;
display: inline;
 
}
.mobile-container {
  min-width: 370px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  background-color: white;
  height: 500px;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
/* TopNav Menu Code from W3Schools.com Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #C61618;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: black;
}
/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #C61618}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  <!-- Contact Us page for OaklandFC -->
<html lang="en-US">
    
 <head>
 <title>Oakland Football Club</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport' />
 <meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=0">
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="description" content="Oakland Football Club">
 <meta name="keywords" content="Football, Soccer, Oakland, Club, family">
 <meta name="author" content="Simply Designed for You">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Oaklandstyle.css" />
 <script src="formValidation.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery-3.5.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>

<body>
 <div id="container1">
 <div id="content-wrap">
  <div id="header">
   <img src="Image/logo.png" alt="Oakland Football logo" />
   <form class="search" action="action_page.php">
    <!--from W3Schools -->
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
   </form>
  </div>
  <div id="navbar">
   <ul>
    <li class="btn"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="btn"><a href="Competitions.html">Competitions</a></li>
    <li class="btn"><a href="Registration.html">Registration</a></li>
    <li class="btn"><a href="Merchandise.html">Merchandise</a></li>
    <li class="btn"><a href="Sponsors.html">Sponsors</a></li>
    <li class="btn"><a href="Information.html">Information</a></li>
    <li class="btn active"><a href="Contact%20Us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="mobile_navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Menu</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="Competitions.html">Competitions</a>
        <a href="Registration.html">Registration</a>
        <a href="Merchandise.html">Merchandise</a>
        <a href="Information.html">Information</a>
        <a href="Contact%20Us.html">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
   <div id="text">
    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="column1">
    <h2>Secretary</h2>
    <p>Name: Laci Tanner </p>
    <p>Phone: 02 - 6620 3324</p>
    <p>Email: <a href="mailto:secretary@oaktownfa.com.au?Subject=Contact%from%Website" target="_top">secretary@oaktownfa.com.au</a></p>
   <br>
    <div id="image_contact" show="@media screen and (max-width: 800px)">
    <img src="Image/soccer.jpg" alt="Oakland Football Team Photo" width="380px"/>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="column2">
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <form action="mailto:secretary@oaktownfa.com.au" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
     <div id="contact_form">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-25">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
       </div>
       <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name" required>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-25">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
       </div>
       <div class="col-75">
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email address" required>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-25">
        <label for="tel">Phone Number</label>
       </div>
       <div class="col-75">
        <input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Your phone number" required>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-25">
        <label for="team">Team</label>
       </div>
       <div class="col-75">
        <select id="team" name="team">
         <option value="PleaseChoose">Please Choose</option>
         <option value="Adults">Adults</option>
         <option value="Under%12s">Under 12s</option>
         <option value="Under%6s">Under 6s</option>
         <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-25">
        <label for="I%am">I am</label>
       </div>
          <div>
         <form action="/action_page.php">
         <input type="radio" id="thinking" name="member" value="thinking">
         <label for="thinking">Thinking about joining the club</label><br>
         <input type="radio" id="member" name="member" value="member">
         <label for="member">Already a member</label><br>
 
         <br>  
         </form></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-25">
        <label for="subject">Message</label>
       </div>
       <div class="col-75">
        <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Message" required style="height:200px"></textarea>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <input type="submit" value="Send">
      </div>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <footer id="footer">
   <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
   Copyright &copy; 2020 Simply Designed For You 
   </footer>
 </div>
</body></html>
```

So this is how it shows when I add it all together. Both menu's and columns not stacking.

Comment: Have you visited [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp) site? They have a nice simple tutorial for something like this that could help you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use the same elements in your navbar on both large and small screens I would recommend not having two separate navbars in your HTML document. If you change one of them later, then you'll also need to update the other one.

W3schools has a good, basic tutorial on [media queries.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp) Media queries provide you with a way of defining special CSS rules based on the size of the browser. So if your site is opened on a smaller device, your navbar will be formatted according to the code in your media query.

Comment: I tried a few I found on there but I couldn't find anything to show how to make the navbar (which I got of w3schools) to resize or change

Comment: Could you post a code snippet where you show what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use media query, But first you need to set up your browser and make it like you're working on a phone to preview what you're doing, so first Press F12 (better use chrome), Look for the phone widget on the top-left , click on it, and start working with Media Query.

For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    body {
       background: red!important;
       /* That means that on a 768px-width screen the body will be red. */
    }
}
```

Comment: But haven't I already done that with the CSS? (but size was 800px) or are you saying i need that line in html as well?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it, But you have to reduce the pixels any time the screen shows any bad elements replacement.
I advice you to learn about Bootstrap framework, it will Save your time!